# Got Error at RunTime because of Required Field Validator

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an ASP.NET Application in VISUAL STUDIO 2013, while adding REQUIRED FIELD VALIDATOR , am getting error at RUNTIME .. and the error is below ... Please Help Me to crack this problem

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
{
[InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.EnsureJqueryRegistered() +2179162
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.RegisterUnobtrusiveScript() +10
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +9708897
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974}
```

Comment: `InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)`.  Looks pretty clear to me....

Comment: will u elaborate .. I cant understand dude and please say how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to the Application_Start method in your `Global.aspx`:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
    {
        Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
        DebugPath = "~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js",
        CdnPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
        CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js"
    });
}
```